# how do I generate unique ids for different component created at runtime as R.java create unique for all calsses

Tags: android

I have to impliment the same logic to generate unique ids in my project for different component created at runtime as R.java does. Some one can help me

Answer (score 2):

If you only need unique ID's at runtime than maybe a singleton which handles the ids can be enough.

```
public class UidUtils {

    private UidUtils() {}

    /**
     * A unique identifier.
     */
    private static int uid = 1;

    /**
     * Deliver the next uid.
     * 
     * @return The next uid.
     */
    public static int getNextUid() {
        return ++uid;
    }

}
```