# How can I programatically generate unique item ids when creating a dynamic menu in Android while not overwriting existing menu item ids?

Tags: java, android, menu

The suggested way of implementing menus in Android is to [use XML to define a menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#xml), which works for static menus. I'm currently trying to create a dynamic sub-menu, though, and I'd like to associate unique item ids with each of the items in a submenu so that I can store metadata with them.

There's an answer here that [suggests using an autoincrementing id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989702/how-do-i-generate-unique-ids-for-different-component-created-at-runtime-as-r-jav), but I also have existing item ids being used for other parts of the menu that look like this (in R.java)

```
public static final int item2=0x7f070002;
```

I'm sure I can start at id = 1 and then increment, but if the id generation scheme ever changes for R.java, I'm worried I'll start seeing collisions. Is there a better way of generating these ids? Or do I just need to keep track of the max id, then start incrementing from there?

Comment: Here's an alternative approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/3217786/1358777 letting the compiler do the work for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "correct" solution would be to traverse the objects that describe the menus to find all of the ids that are in use, then use a different one.

But, if you are prepared to live with a small chance of a problem, you could simply generate your dynamic menu ids using a random number generator.  Assuming you have 32 bit ids, the probablility of a single collision menu item colliding is `N / 2^32` where `N` is the number of existing menu ids.  If we assume a reasonable value for `N`, that's a pretty small number ...

Comment: What I was really hoping for was the ability to add an item and say "just generate a unique, non-used item id for me", and then store whatever was returned. But adding an item with Menu.NONE seems to set all the ids to Menu.NONE.